# How do you find a widget ID without an implemented widget provider?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

Basically I've created a custom notification using `RemoteView` and need to update a `TextView` in that remote view periodically.

From what I understand I need to update the `RemoteView` via the `AppWidgetManager`, more specifically using the method `partiallyUpdateAppWidget (int appWidgetId, RemoteViews views)`

Is there a way I can supply the correct `appWidgetId` without an `AppWidgetProvider`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a notification (be it the `RemoteView` associated with it or any of the notification fields themselves), you must recreate the entire notification, calling `notificationManager.notify()` with the same id as previously added. That will update the notification in place.